# Creating advanced website by redirecting and replacing content from Google Sites

Tags: php, dynamic, idea

I would like to create a corporate website with members area. Importantly, I want many novice webadmins to be able to modify static content themselves.

Therefore, I got the idea to create the site using Google Sites and insert elements with width and height in places where I want dynamic content. The website would be read using PHP on a different server and the marker elements would be replaced with dynamic content created by PHP.

What would be the drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: or just load IFRAMES containing the google site content pages into the main website?

Comment: @DarkcatStudios I thought about this, but if I have several static content parts on each page, like header footer, and various static content spread all over, then my novice users would not be able to change any of the layout on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that going down that track the easier and safer option would be to simply define the user editable elements as WYSIWYG editors. This would allow the use to add an remove content as they wish without needing to be aware of HTML or anything like that.

To answer your specific question the drawback to what you are doing there are a few that I can think of of the top of my head.

1. Any change Google makes to the way sites.google.com renders the content would break your code and you would need to update the code to make it work again, not exactly a sustainable proposition.
2. This would violate Google terms of service which specifically state...

> don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide

3. If this where to be discovered by Google it would bring your entire operation to a halt as Google would more than likely terminate your sites profile which would prevent you from doing anything with it until you did a major revision to your system to support the content changes you want to support without depending on Google Sites.